# Sublime Text 3 Sidebar Color

Tags: themes, sublimetext3, sidebar

I always use dark colors for editor

With sublimetext3 I can not change the color of the sidebar, how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options. The first is to download a [theme](https://packagecontrol.io/browse/labels/theme) from Package Control that has dark backgrounds - I personally prefer [`Theme - Soda`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Theme%20-%20Soda) with the `Soda Dark 3.sublime-theme` setting in your user preferences.

The other option is to modify your `.sublime-theme` file yourself. The following will set the background of the sidebar to black:

```js
{
    "class": "sidebar_container",
    "layer0.tint": [0, 0, 0], // this is the color setting
    "layer0.opacity": 1.0,
    "layer0.inner_margin": [1, 1, 2, 1],
    "content_margin": [0, 0, 1, 0]
},
```

Comment: @Grookier that completely depends on your operating system. The term to search for is "menu bar".